# Ajax call to a ASP.NET MVC web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an MVC app and I'm trying to make a AJAX connection to an web API controller I have. The only error I can surface is "Unidentified". Also In my api controller delete action I'm throwing a random exception so I can detect if I successfully get into the method but I don't.

UPDATE:

Ok It seems I was forgetting the "removeFile" route on my url in the ajax call but the issue is If I add on a "data" attribute to the ajax call to pass in my serialized form controls it stops working properly.

data: $("#frmManipulate").serialize()

Ajax call:

```
$("#frmManipulate").submit(function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all selected files?")) {
            if ($(this).data('clicked').is('[name="delete"]')) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "api/file/removeFile",
                    data: $("#frmManipulate").serialize()
                }).complete(function ($data) {
                    alert("done");
                });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Web API Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/file")]
public class ManipulateController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    [Route("removeFile")]
    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void DeleteFile(string[] url)
    {
        foreach (var file in url)
        {
            throw new MarshalDirectiveException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making DELETE request without a message body.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. And either way I want to pass my form controls to it.

Comment: try adding the [HttpDelete] attribute to the controller method, and then try doing a delete request

Comment: DELETE cannot have a message body.